# Using variable values in function names

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a series of functions which are differently defined based upon 3 integers. I'd like to use the variable values in the function name. This can be achieved using if-else statements:

```
if (i == 0 and j == 0 and t == 0) {
    return E_0_0_0(args);
}
else if (i == 1 and j == 0 and t == 0) {
    return E_1_0_0(args);
}
...
```

The problem with this is that there are a large number of these possibilities and this part of the program is very time-sensitive. Can I use anything to call a function `E_i_j_t(args)` using custom values for `i, j, t` based on the variables? I have looked into preprocessor statements but got a bit lost.

Comment: You can have an `std::array/std::vector` of function pointers.

Comment: An array of function pointers, perhaps.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution, I'd never heard of function pointers, thanks. Is it convenient to define this for the preprocessor to avoid reinitialising the array each time I call this function?

Comment: I think you must re-design your code... you can have template function to specialize by tag for example. Using macro in this way seems a complication for me

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, there are probably better ways to do it than have a bunch of functions like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CALL(x,y,v) f##x##y(v)

void f00(int v) { printf("00\n"); }
void f10(int v) { printf("10\n"); }
void f14(int v) { printf("14\n"); }

int main() {
        CALL(0,0,0);
        CALL(1,0,0);
        CALL(1,4,0);
}
```

`##` is an operator that just catenates its left and right "values" after having replaced arguments of the macro.

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I'm looking for, but when I use variables it just tries to call the function with the variable name instead of the value. Is there any way to mitigate that?

Comment: @obackhouse alas no, the remaining solution is then to use an array of function pointers...

Comment: That's what I'm going for. I'm just going to initialise it outside of the function so that it doesn't need to be re-initialised every time I call it.

Answer (score 0):

A macro like this one might help:

```
#define if_match_invoke_E(_i, _j, _t) \
  if (i == _i && j == _j && t == _t) { \
    E_ ## _i ## _ ## _j ## _ ## _t(args); \
  }
```

Then:

```
if_match_invoke_E(0, 0, 0)
else if_match_invoke_E(1, 0, 0)
```

An array of function pointers might also work:

```
void (*)(args_t) E[] = { E_0_0_0, E_1_0_0 };
E[i](args);
```

In general however it is a poor design to have functions like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a c++ programmer, then you might consider using none-type template parameter. I guess you are using this as some means of versioning; In that case, defining the desired version as a consexpr id and using it as the default template value might come in handy.